# Retrieving Hash Password error

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, hash

I am trying to log on with a username and original password that already stored in the database with a hashed password.

But, when I am trying to log on, I received the message says that `value cannot be null` on `if (salt == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("salt");
        }`

I am using `BCrypt.cs` for hashing the password in the database. [BCrypt.cs](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/10/bcrypt-dotnet-strong-password-hashing-for-dotnet-and-mono.ashx)

Here is my code for register the user:

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=..\db1.accdb";

Password.Hashed = BCrypt.HashPassword(this.textBox2.Text, BCrypt.GenerateSalt(12));

                using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    string query = "INSERT INTO [Member] ([Username], [Password], [UserType]) VALUES (@Username, @Password, @UserType)";

                    conn.Open();

                    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                        cmd.Parameters["@Username"].Value = this.textBox1.Text;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                        cmd.Parameters["@Password"].Value = Password.Hashed;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserType", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                        cmd.Parameters["@UserType"].Value = this.comboBox1.SelectedItem;

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        System.Media.SoundPlayer _sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Exclamation.wav");
                        _sound.Play();

                        DialogResult _dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Added Successfully!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

                        if (_dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
                        {
                            this.Hide();

                            Login _login = new Login();
                            _login.ShowDialog();

                            this.Close();
                        }
                    }

                    conn.Close();
                }
```

Here is my code for log on the user:

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=..\db1.accdb";

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string query = "SELECT [Username], [Password], [UserType] FROM [Member] WHERE [Username] = @Username AND [Password] = @Password";

                conn.Open();

                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters["@Username"].Value = this.textBox1.Text;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
                    cmd.Parameters["@Password"].Value = BCrypt.CheckPassword(this.textBox2.Text, Password.Hashed);

                    using (OleDbDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (dReader.Read())
                        {
                            UserInformation.CurrentLoggedInUser = (string)dReader["Username"];
                            UserInformation.CurrentLoggedInUserType = (string)dReader["UserType"];

                            this.Hide();

                            this.Close();
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            Validation(sender, e);

                            RecursiveClearTextBoxes(this.Controls);
                        }

                        dReader.Close();
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here is the password class:

```
public static string Hashed
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated and your answer much appreciated!

Thank you so much.

**EDITED:**

My database looks like this:

[image]

That password was hashed (salt) and my original password that I use for the login is `Kaoru`. That password was generated from original password, which is `Kaoru`

Comment: You generate random salt and don't save it in database. It's impossible to verify password.

Comment: I agree with Ulugbek. You generate a random salt and never save it anywhere to reuse to compare with the password

Comment: Actually the given implementation of BCrypt.cs combines together salt and hash into one string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=..\db1.accdb";

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    string query = "SELECT [Username], [Password], [UserType] FROM [Member] WHERE [Username] = @Username";

    conn.Open();

    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@Username"].Value = this.textBox1.Text;

        using (OleDbDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            bool isValidPassword = false;
            if (dReader.Read())
            {
                string password = (string)dReader["Password"];
                bool isValidPassword = BCrypt.CheckPassword(this.textBox2.Text, password);
                if (isValidPassword)
                {
                    UserInformation.CurrentLoggedInUser = (string)dReader["Username"];
                    UserInformation.CurrentLoggedInUserType = (string)dReader["UserType"];
                    this.Hide();
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
            if (!isValidPassword)
            {
                Validation(sender, e);

                RecursiveClearTextBoxes(this.Controls);
            }
        }
    }
}
```